# Running watir scripts in multiple browsers simultaneously

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, watir-webdriver

I have watir Scripts which i'm executing in firefox every time they are executed. IS there any way i can run scripts in multiple Browsers simultaneously? Im using rspec and watir-webdriver

or i want the set of scripts to execute first in one browser and then after completion execute in second browser with out duplicating code? is this possible

Answer (score 0):

There are grid testing frameworks, which execute tests in parallel in their own VMs (or processes).

- You can try [watirgrid](https://github.com/90kts/watirgrid), which satisfies your requirement to not duplicate code. It's a bit dated though.
- Another option is [Selenium Grid 2](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) with watir-webdriver (which uses Selenium under the hood)
- You can also do it with Jenkins. Check out the following post:
  http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/29/running-your-watir-webdriver-tests-in-the-cloud-for-free/

Answer (score 0):

Answer would be not straight forward however, try test load balancer
https://github.com/test-load-balancer . you have examples there which can get you started in no time.
We are a global website and we have implemented this for our framework which had similar requirement like yours and it did the trick for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Selenium. I recommend you to look at this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYhJ7c4YKzQ&feature=youtu.be) on Youtube which shows you as an example how to use Selenium as a Service as a post-build option when you build your application with Jenkins.